# ASP.NET Post Method with IEnumerable

Tags: asp.net, post, asp.net-core

**Objetive:** Save multiple items that were edited on a grid.

**Question:** Don't know how to define the Post Method.

Hello,

I have a grid/table of registers I present to the user for him to update it. This is the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Application.Models.Machine>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Test";

}

<h2>Management</h2>
<hr />
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Serial</th>
            <th>Store</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input asp-for="@item.MchName" readonly class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="@item.MchName" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <select asp-for="@item.StoreID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.StoreID">
                            <option value="">-- Seleccione Tienda --</option>
                        </select>
                        <span asp-validation-for="@item.StoreID" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
 </tr>
 }
</tbody>
</table>

 <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Once it's edited it should be saved and the registers modified must be updated but I don't have idea how to define the POST Method in a case of an IEnumerable.

*Following Ibro comment:*

I've done this, first a new class that contains the IEnumerable of the model:

```
public class EditMachineViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Application.Models.Machine> Machines { get; set; }
}
```

**Sidenote** Altough I made the IEnumerable public instead of private.

As for the second part I defined the POST method this way:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Test")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Test(EditMachineViewModel model)
    {
        var machinestoUpdate = await _context.Machines;
        if (await TryUpdateModelAsync(
            machinestoUpdate,
            "",
            s => s.MchName, s => s.StoreID, s => s.PUnit, s => s.Status))
        {
            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. " +
                    "Try again, and if the problem persists, " +
                    "see your system administrator.");
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

Some things happened here:

**1** On this line:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Test(EditMachineViewModel model)
```

Error message: 'MachinesController.Test(EditMachineViewModel)': Not all code paths return a value

But well, this isn't done yet so it's natural to show an error.

**2** On this line:

```
var machinestoUpdate = await _context.Machines;
```

Error message: 'DbSet doesn't have a definition for 'GetAwaiter', but actually (following an old example) this line should end with:

```
.SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == id);
```

But I don't think I can use that since I'm not passing an ID.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You should really use separate methods (actions) for POST:

```
        [HttpGet, ActionName("Edit")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> EditPost(int? id)

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> EditPost(EditMachineViewModel model)

public class EditMachineViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Application.Models.Machine> Machines { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hello, Ibro. I followed your suggestions and updated the first post. I wonder about one line that might be incomple on my side, it's on bullet #2. Could you give me your input? Thanks!